# Laravel multiple Modles query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

hey i have looked at quite a few articles now but i think my knowledge hinders me from adapting any example so here i am, hoping you can help:

What i want: Have an eloquent query which looks in 2 tables

What i have:

```
$myProfile = \App\User::with('friends')->where('friend_type','2')->get();
```

is my wished for result.
In my User Model i have the following:

```
    public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class);
}
```

and in my friends model:

```
    public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

also what i have tried, too:

```
$myProfile = \App\User::with(['friends'])->where('friend_type','2')->get();
```

or

```
$myProfile = \App\User::with('friends')->where('friends.friend_type',2)->get();
```

but the error i receive remains the same:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'friends.friend_type' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `friends`.`friend_type` = 2 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all users whose `friend_type` is `2` then you should use `whereHas`. It would be like

```
\App\User::whereHas('friends', function($q){
  $q->where('friends.friend_type',2)
})->get();
```

Comment: exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the following would to the trick:

```
User::with(['friends' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('friend_type', 2);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Your comment drove me into the right direction, but it resulted in giving me all users, users who have empty ads as well as those who have ad_type 2. i wished to have only those with ad type 2. so i have to accept the answer from abdullah, thank you very much though thomas!